# Checkmarx detecting Vulnerability in Model class

Tags: c#, security, checkmarx

I have recently received a vulnerability report for my project, build using tool "CheckMarx".
I'm ok with many of the results but it is even pointing some simple C# Model classes as vulnerable.

for example:-

```
    public class abc
    {
         public string UserId{get;set;}
         public string ClientId{get;set;}
         public string UserName{get;set;}
         public string EToken{get;set;}
    }
```

I don't understand what exactly causing vulnerable behaviour.

Comment: What does it say the class is vulnerable to? Surely it also gives some context, without context I don't see how code can be vulnerable to anything.

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Even report is also not stating anything specific related and Listing this similar model files as most vulnerable. 

In addition, I had a discussion with my colleague and he suggested may be checkmarx is catching these property name like "Token" or "UserId" as unsecured? And showing this as a vulnerable file. Not sure if it is doing like this.